# Mocha testing difference between done() and done as paramter to function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

please explain difference between done() method and done keyword passed as a parameter to a function?

```
it("qwerty",function(done){
  ------
  ------
  done();
});

it('qwerty', function(done){
  ----------
  ----------
  .expect(404, done);
})
```

Please explain the differences and how many times i can call done() in loop
if i am calling like 15 times i am getting an error "multiple times done() called"

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you call it explicitly. In the second one, you pass `done` function as a callback to `expect`. It checks the response status (I assume you use `supertest` library) and if it equals to 404, calls `done` function without parameter (no error). Otherwise it calls `done` with something like an instance of assertation error, so mocha knows that this is a failed test.

As a regular callback, `done` is not supposed to be called multiple times. It should be called only once, denoting the end of some action, the test in your case. If you are looking for the ability to fail the test, just `throw` it.